# Spring Boot 2.0 fails to work with Caffeine as cache provider

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I create Spring Boot 2.0 Starter project using web and cache dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then I updated Spring bootstrap class to test REST services caching:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping
    @Cacheable("hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

and specified simple cache provider in application.properties:

```
spring.cache.type=simple
```

Everything worked as expected. Then I added Caffeine dependency and changed cache type:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>

spring.cache.type=caffeine
```

After that application failed to start with exception:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No cache manager could be auto-configured, check your configuration (caching type is 'CAFFEINE')
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator.checkHasCacheManager(CacheAutoConfiguration.java:151) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]

I tried to supply cache names in application.properties but it didn't help.

```
spring.cache.cache-names=hello
```

Please advise.

Comment: If I remove spring.cache.type property then application starts but it seems it switches to simple cache provider

Comment: Following the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-caffeine) you need to define the `spring.cache.type` only if you need to force the none value; as caffeine is managed and auto-configured. It can be a regression :/ Can you use **Hazelcast**, just to be sure ??

Comment: I don't have HazelCast but I have Redis installed. So I added Redis dependency: spring-boot-starter-data-redis and changed cache type: spring.cache.type=redis. After that caching worked properly and I saw cache entries on the Redis server.

Comment: Is it a project constraint to use Caffeine? As if it a bug, it may take a while. Redis has pretty cool stuffs, suitable for horizontale scaling.. handling shared sessions, etc.

Comment: No,it's not a constraint. I just wanted to check how Spring Cache works with Caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this is top secret ? Why wasn't tell about it on follow official document:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-caching

Comment: This is not required  , as this dependency is already inside the spring-boot-starter-cache dependency

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, and I also have Redis installed. `spring.cache.type=caffeine` wouldn't work, as well as `spring.cache.caffeine.spec`. It seemed that it tried to use the Redis cache provider, which has precedence over Caffeine, unless you disable Redis auto-configuration explicitly. Otherwise you have to configure Caffeine manually like:

```java
@Configuration
public class CaffeineCacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CaffeineCache helloCache = new CaffeineCache("hello",
                Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build());
        SimpleCacheManager manager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        manager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList(helloCache));
        return manager;
    }
}
```